# What is the accepted best practice for Java type conversions?

Tags: java, type-conversion

What is the current best practice for all the type conversions necessary in a Java web application?  For example, `HttpServletRequest.getParameters(...)` returns `String[]`, but Hibernate does not allow `String[]` to be used in an IN clause for a numeric column.  Therefore I need to convert `String[]` to `Long[]` via `Long.valueOf()`.  What is the best way to handle this, short of rewriting in another language?  Do people just create a class full of little static methods to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a JAX-RS implementation like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), you'll get much improved parameter handling and could map it directly to a List.

If you don't want to go that far, you could also pull tricks like using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `Collections2.transform` and a `Function<String, Long>` on an `Arrays.asList` view of the array.  Not the most compact way, but each piece is reusable so it wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: This is a good suggestion.  I have used Jersey and it is great, but right now I have a Struts application in need of a rewrite.  I could migrate to Jersey, but I might as well migrate to Grails.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the best way to handle this, short of rewriting in another language?

Seriously? Just because all those hip new languages have a compact syntax for transforming lists/arrays, it doesn't mean using a loop will infect you with a terminal disease or anything.

```
Long[] result = new Long[param.length];
for(int i=0; i<param.length; i++){
    result[i] = Long.valueOf(param[i]);
}
```

There, that wasn't so bad, was it? And yeah, you can and should put it in a static helper method if you use it in several places.

**Edit:**
Since Hibernate can also take collections, a somewhat cleaner version:

```
List<Long> result = new ArrayList<Long>();
for(String s : param){
    result.add(Long.valueOf(s));
}
```

Comment: IMO, it is pretty bad.  All this noise takes time to write and more time to read.  Surely I'm about the 17,000,000th Java programmer to write this loop.  That's why I'm asking the community.  Does every Java programmer in the world write junk like this over and over again?  I'm annoyed that I even have to think about this.

Comment: @kevin cline: until Java gets closures (alas, not in Java 7) there isn't really anything that can be done about it; writing it yourself is easier and faster than finding an including a library that does it. And actually, it can be done with somewhat less noise since Hibernate takes collections as well as arrays.

Comment: good point about Hibernate and collections.  No closures in Java 7?  By the time Java moves into the 21st century there won't be anyone still using it.

Comment: That's why people are switching to Groovy and Scala.

Comment: @Kaleb - yes, I'm one of them, but I still have Java code to maintain for another few months.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: I don't think closures are the solution here--the right solution would be for Java to offer native methods to do things like copy numeric values between arrays of different types, copy data between arrays of different size integer types *as though* bitwise copied on big-endian or little-endian architectures (on a big-endian machine, the big-endian method could use a straight block copy; likewise the little-endian method on a little-endian machine), copy every Ith element within a range of one array to every Jth element of another, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons NumberUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html) is best. The conversion routines in the JDK like to just throw a `NumberFormatException` on unparseable strings. This lib allows you to specify a default value for failed parsing.

Comment: These functions only handle scalar conversions.  They don't handle the need for conversion of collections or arrays from one type to another, as described in my example.

Comment: So, write a loop? I assume you have some layers in between your request params and your database updates.

Comment: Ok, I think I see now. You aren't really asking about type conversions, but about request parameter binding. The "standard" Java approach would be to use an MVC framework like Spring MVC that has [request param mapping annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam).

Comment: Sounds good if I can integrate that into my existing Struts 1 application.